# BASH: Performing decimal division on a column in file and printing result in another file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file (in.txt) with the following columns:

```
# DM      Sigma      Time (s)     Sample    Downfact
78.20    7.36    134.200512    2096883      70
78.20    7.21    144.099904    2251561      70
78.20    9.99    148.872384    2326131     150
78.20   10.77    283.249664    4425776      45
```

I want to write a bash script to divide all values in column 'Time' by 0.5867, get a precision up to 2 decimal points and print out the resulting values in another file out.txt

I tried using bc/awk but it gives this error.

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: division by zero attempted
awk: fatal: cannot open file `file' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

This is the bash script that I attempted:

```
cat in.txt | while read DM Sigma Time Sample Downfact; do
echo "$DM      $Sigma      $Time     $Sample    $Downfact"                                                                                            
pperiod = 0.5867                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
awk -v n=$Time 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n", (n/$pperiod)}'                                                                                                  
#echo "scale=2 ; $Time / $pperiod" | bc                                                                                                                 
#echo "$subint" > out.txt                                                                                                                            
done
```

I expected the script to divide column 'Time' with pperiod and get the result with a precision of 2 decimal places. This result should be printed to a file named out.txt

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output (ie, contents of `out.txt`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of issues with current `awk` code:

- need to pass in the value of the `$pperiod` variable
- need to reference the `Time` column by is position (`$3` in this case)
- `BEGIN{}` block is applied before any input lines are processed and has nothing to do with processing of actual input lines
- there is no code to perform processing on actual input lines
- need to decide what to do in the case of a `divide by zero` scenario (in this case we'll default answer to `0.00`)
- **NOTE:** current code generates `divide by zero` error because `$pperiod` is an undefined (`awk`) variable which in turn defaults to `0`
- additionally, `pperiod = 0.5867` is invalid `bash` syntax

One idea for fixing current issues:

```
pperiod=0.5867 
awk -v pp="${pperiod}" 'NR>1 {printf "%.2f\n", (pp==0 ? 0 : ($3/pp))}' in.txt > out.txt
```

Where:

- `-v pp="${pperiod}"` - assign `awk` variable `pp` the value of the `bash` variable `"${pperiod}"`
- `NR>1` - skip header line
- `NR>1` {printf "%.2f\n" ...}`- for each input line, other than the header line, print the result of dividing the`Time`column (aka`$3`) by the value of the` awk`variable`pp`(which holds the value of the`bash`variable`"${pperiod}"`)
- `(pp==0 ? 0 : ($3/pp))` - if `pp` is equal 0 we print `0` else print result of `$3/pp)` (this keeps us from generating a `divide by zero error`)
- **NOTE:** this also eliminates the need for the `cat|while` loop

This generates:

```
$ cat out.txt
228.74
245.61
253.75
482.78
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This has been extremely helpful for a beginner like me.